# Why is the const version of a member function always selected even the non-const version exists?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, constants, overloading, member-functions

**Update: This is a wrong question. There is no non-const version of string::data(); ignore this question. I'm sorry!**

`string::data` has a const version and a non-const version. In my following code, `str` is obviously a non-const object, so `str.data()` should call the non-const version. However, VC++ 2013 doesn't think so.

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void f1(char* sz)
{}

template<class stringT>
void f2(stringT& str)
{
    f1(str.data());
}

int main()
{
    string s;

    f2(s);
    // error C2664: 'void f1(char *)' : 
    // cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char *' to 'char *'
}
```

Comment: string.data() returns const char*  ; http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/data/

Comment: _"string::data has a const version and a non-const version"_  No it doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `string::data` has a const version and a non-const version.

No, it doesn't.  [There is only a `const` version.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data)